# Calling one service activator and another service activator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a doubt in Spring Integration Flow. Can we call one int:service-activator after another . Consider below example.

```
<int:channel id="getPresciption" />
<int:channel id="respPrescription" />       

<int-http:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="getPresciption" reply-channel="respPrescription"
    supported-methods="GET" path="/getAllPresciption">

    <int-http:request-mapping
        consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator
    ref="medicineServiceActivator" method="buildPrescription"
    input-channel="respPrescription"  output-channel="respPrescription" />

<int:service-activator
    ref="medicineServiceActivator" method="storePrescription"
    input-channel="respPrescription"></int:service-activator>
```

My Qoestion is can we do this. 
or we have to use Aggregator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another channel

```
<int:service-activator
    ref="medicineServiceActivator" method="buildPrescription"
    input-channel="respPrescription"  output-channel="toStorePrescription" />

<int:service-activator
    ref="medicineServiceActivator" method="storePrescription"
    input-channel="toStorePrescription"></int:service-activator>
```

Comment: means we can call a service activator after another service activator

Comment: Right - the output of the first is sent to the second.

Comment: i tried using this. but after using this i am getting below exception when ever i hit the url.

Comment: The error message is quite clear; you have no subscribers on `getPresciption`. Your first service has the same input and output channel `respPrescription`. The input channel should be `getPresciption`.

Comment: Thanks. One more question how can we have more then one method in our gateway interface. I mean ya we can have it but how we map it if we have more than 1 methods

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; particularly unrelated ones - it won't help the community find answers. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-configuration-annotations). By default, all methods will send messages to the same channel, but you can override the gateway configuration for each method.